# How to Change the Font of a Specific <li>

Tags: css, html-lists

I cannot figure out the proper CSS selector to target changing the font of only one list item. Here's the layout

```
<ul id="menu-applemain class="x-nav>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

I'm actually able to select the correctlist item via 
`#menu-applemain li:nth-child(4){  }` I can change the background color but not the font, even when using !important. I'm pretty sure I need target the li a in order to change the font. I'm just not sure of the selector. I've tried `#menu-applemain li a:nth-child(4){  }` but that doesn't work.

Comment: what is your css to change the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried to close quotation marks?

```css
#menu-applemain li:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-applemain" class="x-nav">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

if u want link:

```css
#menu-applemain li:nth-child(4) a {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-applemain" class="x-nav">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple methods to target the proper li in your code.

**1.You can target it by its position using the following code:**

```
#menu-applemain > li:nth-child(HERE_YOU_PUT_THE_ORDER_OF_THE_ELEMENT) {
   font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

> you can read more about how to use the nth-child function in css here:
>   [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

**2.You can give the li an id like the following**

```
<li id="target-li">example</li>
```

then

```
#menu-applemain > #target-li {
   font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this also seems like a good way to go, but the other suits my situation a little more convenient.